# Swift UITableViewCell fails to setup its constraint after cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

In my tableViewController i use a custom cell which contains an imageView, two labels and some other irrelevant elements. Also there's a constraint, of which the constant value shall be changed, if a certain condition is given. This works fine on the first sight but if i scroll down and get cells where the constraint constant is set to another value the some of the following cells kinda keep this constant from this previous cell and don't set it up at appearing.

This is the relevant part of my cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = whichCellToShow ? "ThisCell" : "TheOtherCellCell"

    //...

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

    if let customCell = cell as? CustomCellProtocol,
       indexPath.section < data.count,
       indexPath.row < data[indexPath.section].count {

        customCell.display(data: data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
    }

    return cell
}
```

These are the relevant parts of my custom cell class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, CustomCellProtocol {
@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weblink: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleIndentationConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
//...

    func display(data: Data) {

        //...

        title.text = data.title

        //...

        weblink.text = data.hasWeblink ? URLUtilities.hostOfURL(urlstr: data.sourceUrl) : nil
        weblink.isHidden = !data.hasWeblink
        //This is the spot where things seem to go wrong
        titleIndentationConstraint.constant = data.hasWeblink ? weblink.frame.height : 0
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

If `data.hasWeblink == true` the constraint constant shall be equal to the height of the weblink label, if it's false it shall be 0.

My first thought was, that the view recycling of UITableView could collide with `titleIndentationConstraint.constant = data.hasWeblink ? weblink.frame.height : 0`. That's why i called `setNeedsLayout()`and `layoutIfNeeded()`straight afterwards, but this doesn't seem to help. All the other elements of the cell do their job correctly.

Also i'm setting `tableView.rowHeight`and `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`inside the `viewDidLoad()` of my tableViewController.

Does anybody have an idea what in particular is going wrong there or what i forgot to do? Thanks in forward!

Comment: Are you deactivating the constraint somewhere?

Comment: @bseh nope, also getting no constraint break warnings in the debugger, but i got another hot track, seems that the title label behaves silly

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it myself, had to change some constraint priorities of the title label:

My title label has a bottom constraint which is always greater or equal than 8 pts. Also i limited the number of lines to 4 and told the label to truncate the text's tail, if it's too long to be displayed. Funnily always, if the text was truncated, i got this silly behavior described above, so it has absolutely nothing to do with my `titleIndetantionConstraint`. Seems like if the text has to be truncated the label aligned itself to the bottom constraint and kinda *dragged* the content to center left (so watch what **content mode** says in the property editor, it should be left by default). While changing the label's content mode seems like a bad idea to me, i lowered the **priority** of the title label bottom constraint by 1 so it aligns itself to the top of the picture, like i planned. Hopefully this helps people how have similar issues B).

Comment: You should delete question